# Bootstrap image responsive not working in IE and Firefox but works fine in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sharepoint

I am facing a weird behavior from bootstrap. I am using img-responsive class for a image in my page using bootstrap. 
my image is fine in Google Chrome it re sizes properly but in FF and IE it is re sizing properly in desktop and I PAD view but when i go lower screen size like phones and i phones it doesn't re-sizes it stays the original size. 
It works fine for Google chrome for every screen resolutions but in IE and FF it doesn't shrink in any single columns sizes. it retains the original size of the image which is very big.

Attached are the images from the web inspector for each browser. 
Firefox
[image]
IE

[image]

GoogleChrome
[image]

Any help

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: i added colxs-12 to the divs then it fixed the issue. I was using the latest bootstrap version 3.3.4

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to the latest version of bootstrap. This has been resolved since version 3.2.1

Related issue : [IE backslash hack on .img-responsive stretches images in IE<11](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13996)

Answer (score 0):

Added col-xs-12 to all the divs being used, then it fixed the issue..